# how to get whole text selected onClick EditText

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext

In a browser we click on search box whole text got selected. like that how to enable this in android EditText. When click on EditText, whole text in it got selected.
Its my first question so please don't critic it.

Comment: just set android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

Comment: If you got an answer, accept anyone as answer!

Comment: @alok First answer was written by Sanju Baghla and then I wrote. Prem has added an answer by adding both of our answers into one answer. And you have marked it as Answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`android:selectAllOnFocus`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:selectAllOnFocus)

> If the text is selectable, select it all when the view takes focus.
>
> May be a `boolean` value, such as "true" or "false".

From `XML`

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

FROM `java`

```
YourEditText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add it in `EditText`

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```